# How do I convert this piece of javascript code to coffeescript code

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

What would following code look like in coffeescript?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      $('#datetime-picker').datetimepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You don't plan to use an [inline `<script type="text/coffeescript">`](http://coffeescript.org/#scripts), do you?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ->
  $("#datetime-picker").datetimepicker()
  return
```

[Source](http://js2coffee.org/)

Comment: @BhushanLodha: Why not?

Comment: What about it isn't working? That's valid CoffeeScript, which is what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
$ ->
  $("#datetime-picker").datetimepicker()
  return
</script>
```

Is indeed the right answer to your question. Unfortunately, browsers don't understand natively *coffeescript*.

But there is a little known feature that allow such piece of code to work. You have to load `coffee-script.js` (for example from `http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/raw/master/extras/`) after all coffeescript on the page. This is the compiler and on loading, it will evaluate and compile all coffeescript previously defined on your page. Of course, compiling coffeescript on each page load is far from being efficient, and it is absolutely not recommended for production code.

Nevertheless, here is a little self contained example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/coffeescript">
$ -> $('#header').css 'color','green'
</script>
<h1 id="header" style="color:red">
  If this is green your browser understand coffescript !!
</h1> 

<!-- Load coffeescript compiler -->
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/raw/master/extras/coffee-script.js"> </script>
</html>
```

**That being said, to quote [the doc](http://coffeescript.org/#scripts):  *"it's not recommended for serious use"***